# Adding a total row

Tags: mysql

I have a query;

```
select ProductID,  name, (unitPrice*quantity) As 'Stock Equity'
from tproduct
group by productID with rollup
;
```

I wish for this to return a set of rows with the last being a calculation of the Total, instead its repeating the last result?

can anyone tell me why and how to overcome this please?

this is the query result at the moment;

```
ProductID    Name           Stock Equity
1            cannon 600 D   3360
2            cannon 550 D   1000
3            cannon 500 D   750
4            cannon 5D      5000
5            cannon 650 D   9000
6            Nikon D5100    1000
7            Nikon D3200    420
8            Nikon D7000    2700
9            Nikon D800     6030
10           Nikon D90      4770
null         Nikon D90      4770
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
select ProductID,  name, (unitPrice*quantity) As 'Stock Equity'
from tproduct
union all
select 'total', 'total', sum(unitPrice*quantity)
from tproduct
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56d73/4)

Or you can use something like this:

```
select case when ProductID is null then 'total' else ProductId end Productid,  
  case when ProductID is null then 'total' else name end name, 
  sum(unitPrice*quantity) As 'Stock Equity'
from tproduct
group by ProductID with rollup
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56d73/6)

Answer (score 0):

```
select ProductID,  
       name, 
       (unitPrice*quantity) As 'Stock Equity',
       (select sum(unitPrice*quantity) from tproduct) As total
from tproduct
group by productID
```